# Unable to import Angular Components styling in SCSS file

Tags: angular, webstorm, angular-dart, scss-mixins

I've been following the [getting-started](https://webdev.dartlang.org/guides/get-started) guide for making an AngularDart Web App. I've got a small app up and running via WebStorm. I added an SCSS Watcher to the project which compiles fine, but throws the following type of error whenever I try to import one of the Angular Component styles:

```
@import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/mixins';
```

> error style.scss (Line 1: File to import not found or unreadable: package:angular_components/app_layout/mixins.)

I am clueless on how to proceed. Would greatly appreciate advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SASS watcher doesn't know about Dart import syntax.

Add instead https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sass_builder instead to `pubspec.yaml` and SASS will be built as part of Darts build process.

Comment: Vielen dank, Günter! Just as things seemed hopeless, you saved the day

Comment: Glad to hear I could help :D